Unable to send ssl file path as URL in dataproc ,spark.read
I am using JDBC to connect to DB2 using Dataproc/Pyspark.
Since it uses secure port, it requires some SSL information as part of the URL:
Here's the format:
jdbc:db2://IP_Addr:PORT/DB:sslConnection=true;sslTrustStoreLocation=gs://gcpBucket/folder/mytrustfile;sslVersion=TLSv1.2;TrustStorePassword=mypasswd;
When I submit this URL to a Dataproc cluster, I get an error stating JavaFileNotFound. And what I observe is that it removes one forward slash from the gs:// , i.e. it passes it as gs:/gcpBucket/folder/mytrustfile
I tried putting escape characters in different ways, but nothing worked i.e. gs:////gcpBucket or gs:///gcpBucket or gs://gcpBucket .
Can anyone suggest what I need to do? Thanks
I tried putting escape characters in different ways, but nothing worked i.e. gs:////gcpBucket or gs:///gcpBucket or gs://gcpBucket .
